# Hadoop, MapReduce Custom Java Counters Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

## Error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.ensureState(Job.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getCounters(Job.java:762)
    at com.aamend.hadoop.MapReduce.CountryIncomeConf.main(CountryIncomeConf.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

The error shows that the problem lies in the line:

> Counter counter =
>        job.getCounters().findCounter(COUNTERS.MISSING_FIELDS_RECORD_COUNT);

Also I do have a enum with the name COUNTERS.

### Mapper :

```
     import java.io.IOException;

        import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
        import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
        import org.apache.log4j.Logger;



  public class CountryIncomeMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {

      private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("FilterMapper");

      private final int incomeIndex = 54;
      private final int countryIndex = 0;
      private final int lenIndex = 58;

      String seperator = ",";

      public void map(Object key, Text line, Context context) throws IOException,
          InterruptedException {

        if (line == null) {
          logger.info("null found.");
          context.getCounter(COUNTERS.ERROR_COUNT).increment(1);
          return;
        }
        if (line.toString().contains(
            "Adjusted net national income per capita (current US$)")) {
          String[] recordSplits = line.toString().split(seperator);

          logger.info("The data has been splitted.");

          if (recordSplits.length == lenIndex) {

            String countryName = recordSplits[countryIndex];
            try {

              double income = Double.parseDouble(recordSplits[incomeIndex]);

              context.write(new Text(countryName), new DoubleWritable(income));

            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

              logger.info("The value of income is in wrong format." + countryName);
              context.getCounter(COUNTERS.MISSING_FIELDS_RECORD_COUNT).increment(1);
              return;
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
```

### Driver Class :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class CountryIncomeConf {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
      InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
    Path outputDir = new Path(args[1]);

    // Create configuration
    Configuration conf = new Configuration(true);

    // Create job
    Job job = new Job(conf, "CountryIncomeConf");
    job.setJarByClass(CountryIncomeConf.class);

     Counter counter =
     job.getCounters().findCounter(COUNTERS.MISSING_FIELDS_RECORD_COUNT);

     System.out.println("Error Counter = " + counter.getValue());

    // Setup MapReduce
    job.setMapperClass(CountryIncomeMapper.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

    // Specify key / value
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

    // Input
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputPath);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    // Output
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputDir);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    // Delete output if exists
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    if (hdfs.exists(outputDir))
      hdfs.delete(outputDir, true);

    // Execute job
    int code = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    System.exit(code);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to get the counter before you submitted the job.

Comment: I think it is working, But now its showing a different error. 
Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter, but class was expected

Do you know what it means and how to resolve it.

Comment: Is there any connection between the error and the version of hadoop I am using, because I am using Hadoop 2.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error at the time of an sqoop export.
The error was generated because the hdfs directory was empty.
Once I populated the directory (corresponding to a hive table), the sqoop ran without problems.